# how to use database in Scala, Lift?

Tags: database, scala, lift

I am able to successfully read the data from my form and using println show them in console,
I need to add them to the database, currently I am using the predefine database for my authorisation stuffs, please help me to add the form values to the database. So far I have created the following class.

```
 object Form extends Form with LongKeyedMetaMapper[Form] {
  override def fieldOrder = List(name,age)
 }

 class Form extends LongKeyedMapper[Form] with IdPK {
  def getSingleton = Form
  object name extends MappedString(this,10)
  object age extends MappedString(this,5)
 }
```

Comment: -1 because, in my opinion, the question is too unspecific and looks as if "follow a Lift tutorial" would be the best answer to come up with.

Comment: @mhs, for sure I went through the tutorials but could not find any useful answer otherwise I was not going to waste my time by asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists an example for setting up Lift Mapper at the Lift wiki-site. See https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mapper